# LaTeX objects to "_Determinant" in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a bibliography as follows.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{frazier} 
F.W. Gehring, Michael W. Frazier, S. Axler.
\textit{Introduction to Wavelets Through Linear Algebra}. 
Springer, 1999.

\bibitem{donohostark} 
David L. Donoho, Philip B. Stark. 
\textit{Uncertainty Principles And Signal Recovery}. 
Siam Journal on Applied Mathematics, Vol. 49, No. 3, pp. 906-931, June 1989.

\bibitem{fftprog} 
\texttt{https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/}

\bibitem{vandermonde} 
\texttt{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant}

\end{thebibliography}
```

When I compile this, I get "Missing $ inserted." on the last line before \end. But when I comment out the word _Determinant, everything works.

```
\texttt{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde}%_Determinant}
```

Is _Determinant some built in function already? I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is the `_` in the given url.  Load package `\usepackage{url}` and write then `\url{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant}` instead of `\texttt{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `_` ("underscore") character in the URL string.  In TeX and LaTeX, `_` is usually interpreted as the beginning of a subscript term in a math formula, and `_` is thus expected to occur in math mode. Hence also the message that `$` is missing (as `$` serves to initiate and terminate inline math mode).

Url strings, of course, use this character without such a special meaning.

So please load package `url` via

```
\usepackage{url}
```

in the preamble and write

```
\url{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant}
```

instead of

```
\texttt{https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant}.
```